# what is the memory footprint?

Tags: programming-languages

what does it mean by memory footprint of a program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Memory_footprint) :

> Memory footprint refers to the amount
> of main memory that a program uses or
> references while running.

*(and more I didn't copy-paste)*